# iPhone Cells being drawn not showing full content till scroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've had a problem like this before but it was to do with the reuse of the cell. Now I know the cuprit line which i'll point out in the code below, but it's been added to make sure the cell text fits properly in the table (changing text sizes from XML feed)

The code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ViewRoutesCell * aCell = (ViewRoutesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ViewRoutesCell"];

    if (aCell == nil)
    {   
        NSArray *arr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewRoutesCell" owner:self options:nil];
        aCell = (ViewRoutesCell *)[arr objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    AssessObject *newObj1;
    newObj1=[totalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newObj1.routeImage]]];

    aCell.imgRoute.image = image;
    aCell.lblRouteText.text = newObj1.routeText;
    aCell.lblRouteImage.text = newObj1.routeImage;
    aCell.txtRoute.text = newObj1.routeText;
    aCell.txtRoute.frame = CGRectMake(aCell.txtRoute.frame.origin.x, aCell.txtRoute.frame.origin.y, aCell.txtRoute.frame.size.width, aCell.txtRoute.contentSize.height);

    return aCell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AssessObject *newObj1;
    newObj1=[totalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *cellText = newObj1.routeText;

    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];


    return labelSize.height + 250;

}
```

Now if i include the line:

```
aCell.txtRoute.frame = CGRectMake(aCell.txtRoute.frame.origin.x, aCell.txtRoute.frame.origin.y, aCell.txtRoute.frame.size.width, aCell.txtRoute.contentSize.height);
```

[This happens (click for video)](http://screencast.com/t/KYwQjgymeU)

However, when I comment that line out this happens:

[Another short video](http://screencast.com/t/XDViFtO9S)

So it shows all the text at the start, but it's cutting the longer text sections out before all the text has been displayed (but making the cell the right height)

I'm very confused!

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting up the `txtRoute` object's `autoresizingMask` property within your nib properly?

Comment: Yeah, well they're set to resize up and down [link](http://content.screencast.com/users/TomBeech/folders/Jing/media/bdf2fe93-8cdc-4f7d-aa78-013c4cb3f172/00000024.png)

Comment: Need to set the bottom anchor as well. You have it set for flexible bottom margin. That should solve it.

Comment: I've added that. It still doesn't show the text untill you scroll down and then up again

Comment: Darn. I do have a couple of observations. While it might not solve anything with this problem, I see you are using an `UITextView` to display this text. Using an `UITextView` inside an `UIScrollView` has its own issues, and you might be better served using an `UITextField' with `numberOfLines` set to 0 (no limit), and `autoresizingMask` as indicated earlier. Also, when I have view sizing issues, I set the `backgroundColor` to a bright color to help visualize what is really going on. That might help reveal the issue in this case.

Comment: I do appreciate all your help matey. I've just tried playing with using a textfield instead of view, however, theres no number of lines property and you can't change the height can you?

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. I meant `UILabel`.